# How do I get the admin.conf file?

Tags: kubernetes, admin

I am new to Kubernetes, got access to some local clusters (via the browser interface) and would like to start working with them now. To do that, I need to download the admin.conf file from the master node. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to ssh to it, and check for the admin.conf file under path: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf

Comment: how exactly do I do that?

Comment: @JDoe6213981 What do you need this file for exactly? and if you're not the one who set up the cluster itself, you can ask the one who did to retrieve it for you, it depends on your environment, what cloud is your environment running on? You can use some tools according to the cloud provider in order to ssh, or use an ssh client - in Windows you can use "PuTTy"(https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404604/using-ssh-in-putty-), on MacOS or linux, a simple "SSH" command (ssh <user>@<host IP> -i <ssh key> , or using a password ... ).